# Count total instances of various strings over 1.8M lines

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to analyse my 1.8M line dataset using Python in the most efficient way.  I know how to do this in a horrible way but am looking for some experts to give me some pointers.
I'm interested in getting some data from 2 fields:

- One field contains one or more Cities from a list of ~1200, separated by `~`.
- The other contains Crimes from a list of ~70
  The output I'm after is the list of each City with a count of those crimes.

Input

| City | Crime |
| --- | --- |
| London~Paris~New York | Mugging~Murder |
| New York~Milan~Paris | Theft |
| Brussels~Paris | Violence~Murder~Hate Crime |
| London | Mugging~GBH |

Output

| City | Crimes |
| --- | --- |
| London | Mugging(2), Murder(1), GBH(1) |
| Paris | Mugging(1), Murder(2), Theft(1), Violence(1), Hate Crime(1) |
| New York | Mugging(1), Murder(1), Theft(1) |
| Milan | Theft(1) |
| Brussels | Violence(1), Murder(1), Hate Crime(1) |

The only way I could think to do this was to set up arrays of each of the 1200 cities and assign a position in each of those arrays that corresponds to the crime.  I'd loop through each city within the City field and add 1 to the corresponding Crime position for that array.
The problem is that I'd need to have many If statements and so a huge amount of set up, something like:

If Crime = Murder then increment London(45) -  if 45 was the position in the array that was "Murder"
etc etc

Is there any way to create some kind of Hash map based on the values rather than specifying all the possibilities beforehand?

Comment: How do you define 'efficient' - fastest, using least memory, shortest or most elegant code? Can you show code you've written to try it the 'horrible' way? Do you have any influence over the format in which this data is provided?

Comment: I guess just good practice.  I've not written any code yet, I just didn't want to go down the route of declaring hundreds of variables if there's a simple clean way

Comment: As a side comment, this is exactly why it's a terrible idea to include multiple things in one column.  If the source data had used a sane format, your job would be much easier.

Comment: This input format is really weird. I'm not sure there is a magic solution, but you can use a global dictionary of dictionaries, and then for each row parse the *city* & *crime* fields, so that you get a proper array of cities & crimes (as a `str` for example), and by iterating each city and every crime do `dictionary[city][crime] += 1`. You would have to make sure the dictionaries exist and are properly initialised first.

Comment: @FerdinandKeller pandas is magic, or at least it's sufficiently advanced technology so as to be indistinguishable :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using `setdefault()` and a `collections.Counter()` to aggregate the data if this was a one time thing. Otherwise, I would try to work with the producer to reshape the data so that one was not needing to parse those columns.

```py
import collections

data_in = """
City,Crime
London~Paris~New York,Mugging~Murder
New York~Milan~Paris,Theft
Brussels~Paris,Violence~Murder~Hate Crime
London,Mugging~GBH
""".strip().split("\n")

data_out = {}
for row in data_in[1:]:
    cities, crimes = row.split(",")
    for city in cities.split("~"):
        target = data_out.setdefault(city, collections.Counter())
        for crime in crimes.split("~"):
            target[crime] += 1

for row in data_out.items():
    print(row)
```

Giving you:

```
('London', Counter({'Mugging': 2, 'Murder': 1, 'GBH': 1}))
('Paris', Counter({'Murder': 2, 'Mugging': 1, 'Theft': 1, 'Violence': 1, 'Hate Crime': 1}))
('New York', Counter({'Mugging': 1, 'Murder': 1, 'Theft': 1}))
('Milan', Counter({'Theft': 1}))
('Brussels', Counter({'Violence': 1, 'Murder': 1, 'Hate Crime': 1}))
```

In the event, you wanted to cast the counters into a string to match your desired result you could add on a step:

```
data_out = [
    [city, ", ".join([f"{k}({v})" for k, v in crimes.items()])]
    for city, crimes
    in data_out.items()
]

for row in data_out:
    print(row)
```

That should give you:

```
['London', 'Mugging(2), Murder(1), GBH(1)']
['Paris', 'Mugging(1), Murder(2), Theft(1), Violence(1), Hate Crime(1)']
['New York', 'Mugging(1), Murder(1), Theft(1)']
['Milan', 'Theft(1)']
['Brussels', 'Violence(1), Murder(1), Hate Crime(1)']
```

Comment: Awesome response.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'm blown away!

Answer (score 2):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) has functions that allow you to do this in a very simple way, which is probably also among the fastest.

```
import pandas as pd
cities_crimes = pd.read_csv("cities_crimes.csv")

# Split each list of Cities into an array, then 
# explode the array items into separate rows
cities_crimes["City"] = cities_crimes["City"].str.split('~')
cities_crimes = cities_crimes.explode("City")

# Do the same for Crimes
cities_crimes["Crime"] = cities_crimes["Crime"].str.split('~')
cities_crimes = cities_crimes.explode("Crime")

# Group the result by City and Crime and count the number of each
city_crime_stats = cities_crimes.groupby(["City", "Crime"]).value_counts()
```

You can save the results with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-store-in-csv), or you can access the stats per city like this:

```
>>> city_crime_stats["Brussels"]
Crime
Hate Crime    1
Murder        1
Violence      1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

or each individual value like this:

```
>>> city_crime_stats["Brussels"]["Murder"]
1
```

Comment: Looks like we both see data frames just begging to be used :). Nice code.

Comment: I think there is a mistake with the last line : `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'values_counts'`

Comment: `.size()` works though.

Comment: Oops, the method is `value_counts` - thanks for spotting the error @FerdinandKeller

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily do this with a nested dictionary.

```
results = {}

for row in dataset:
    cities = row[0]
    crimes = row[1]

    for city in cities.split("~"):
        # if we have not seen this city yet, make a new sub-dictionary
        # to store its crimes
        if city not in results:
            results[city] = {}

        for crime in crimes.split("~"):
            # if we have not seen this crime in this city yet,
            # record one occurrence of this crime
            if crime not in results[city]:
                results[city][crime] = 1
            # otherwise add one more occurrence of this crime
            else:
                results[city][crime] += 1
```

End result will look like this:

```
{
    "London": {
        "Mugging": 2,
        "Murder": 5,
    },
    "Brussels": {
        "Mugging": 1,
        "Theft": 2,
    },
    ... etc.
}
```

Comment: If you use `collections.defaultdict` and initialise `result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))` then you can just do `results[city][crime] += 1` without needing to test whether the city or crime keys are already there.

Answer (score 0):

With large input you can try polars:

```
import polars as pl
from polars import col

input_fn = "foo.tsv"

df = pl.read_csv(input_fn, separator="\t", has_header=False, new_columns=["cities", "crimes"] )

df = df.with_columns(pl.all().str.split("~")).explode("cities").explode("crimes").sort(["cities","crimes"])
```

The above gives you:

```
┌──────────┬────────────┐
│ cities   ┆ crimes     │
│ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str      ┆ str        │
╞══════════╪════════════╡
│ Brussels ┆ Hate Crime │
│ Brussels ┆ Murder     │
│ Brussels ┆ Violence   │
│ London   ┆ GBH        │
│ London   ┆ Mugging    │
│ …        ┆ …          │
│ Paris    ┆ Mugging    │
│ Paris    ┆ Murder     │
│ Paris    ┆ Murder     │
│ Paris    ┆ Theft      │
│ Paris    ┆ Violence   │
└──────────┴────────────┘
```

Some grouping and counting required:

```
result_df = df.group_by(["cities", "crimes"],  maintain_order=True).count()
```

Giving:

```
┌──────────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ cities   ┆ crimes     ┆ count │
│ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ str        ┆ u32   │
╞══════════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ Brussels ┆ Hate Crime ┆ 1     │
│ Brussels ┆ Murder     ┆ 1     │
│ Brussels ┆ Violence   ┆ 1     │
│ London   ┆ GBH        ┆ 1     │
│ London   ┆ Mugging    ┆ 2     │
│ …        ┆ …          ┆ …     │
│ Paris    ┆ Hate Crime ┆ 1     │
│ Paris    ┆ Mugging    ┆ 1     │
│ Paris    ┆ Murder     ┆ 2     │
│ Paris    ┆ Theft      ┆ 1     │
│ Paris    ┆ Violence   ┆ 1     │
└──────────┴────────────┴───────┘
```